# SELECT TOP 1 ...Some stuff... ORDER BY DES gives different result

Tags: sql

```
SELECT TOP 1 Col1,col2
FROM table ... JOIN table2
...Some stuff...
 ORDER BY DESC
```

gives different result. compared to

```
SELECT Col1,col2
FROM table ... JOIN table2
...Some stuff...
 ORDER BY DESC
```

2nd query gives me some rows , When I want the Top 1 of this result I write the 1st query with TOP 1 clause. These both give different results.

why is this behavior different

Comment: Assuming it's SQL Server, if you try "TOP 1 WITH TIES", what do you get as result? Also... Can you post the more of the SQL? Specially, the source (table) from Col1, Col2 and the ORDER BY? Finally, it wouldn't hurt to have some data.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't very clear, but I guess you mean the row returned by the first query isn't the same as the first row returned by the second query. This could be because your order by has duplicate values in it.

Say, for example, you had a table called Test

```
+-----+------+
| Seq | Name |
+-----+------+
| 1   | A    |
| 1   | B    |
| 2   | C    |
+-----+------+
```

If you did `Select * From Test Order By Seq`, either of these is valid

```
+-----+------+
| Seq | Name |
+-----+------+
| 1   | A    |
| 1   | B    |
| 2   | C    |
+-----+------+

+-----+------+
| Seq | Name |
+-----+------+
| 1   | B    |
| 1   | A    |
| 2   | C    |
+-----+------+
```

With the top, you could get either row.

Having the top 1 clause could mean the query optimizer uses a completely different approach to generate the results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you're working in SQL Server, so Laurence's answer is probably accurate. But for completeness, this also depends on what database technology you are using.

Typically, index-based databases, like SQL Server, will return results that are sorted by the index, depending on how the execution plan is created. But not all databases utilize indices.

Netezza, for example, keeps track of where data lives in the system without the concept of an index (Netezza's system architecture is quite a bit different). As a result, selecting the 1st record of a query will result in a random record from the result set floating to the top. Executing the same query multiple times will likely result in a different order each time.

If you have a requirement to order data, then it is in your best interest to enforce the ordering yourself instead of relying on the arbitrary ordering that the database will use when creating its execution plan. This will make your results more predictable.

Answer (score -3):

Your 1st query will get one table's top row and compare with another table with condition. So it will return different values compare to normal join.